# Failing an RPM install programmatically in a spec step

Tags: fedora, rpm

I'm making an RPM. This particular RPM has requirements that can't be expressed as RPM prerequisites, lets call them a particular filesystem/disk configuration. Currently the failure happens after install, at runtime, when the requirements aren't met.

I can check for the required prerequisites in the %install, section of my script. However, I can't figure out how to fail the install if certain criteria are met. Is it possible to fail an rpm install at runtime via some trigger in the %install (or some other) section?

An example would look something like so, in a .spec file:

```
%install
if [ -f /some/file ]
then
    FAIL_RPM_INSTALL ## What is this command?
fi
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turns out that if you exit in the `%pre` stage the rpm install will fail.

```
%pre
if [ -f /some/file ]
then
    echo "/some/file exists, it shouldn't"
    exit 1
fi
```

Reference: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:ScriptletSnippets

Answer (score 3):

```
%pre
df /data|awk 'END{if ($2 < 10000000) exit 1;}'; 
if [ $? == 1 ]; 
    then echo ERROR not enough space;exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: awk will give you wrong value when *file system* name is too long. I belive using `df -P` avoids this issue.